# Sql Server: How to Deny users access to linked servers

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions

I'd like to deny access to query linked servers to a group of users. I've put them in a role and assigned certain permissions to object level permissions to the that group. I'm at a loss after searching BOL and 'net how to DENY access to linked servers.

EDIT:

I decided to break out profiler to verify exactly what SSMS is calling when displaying linked servers and ensure that a DENY was issued on that system view/SP. Turns out it calls sys.servers, but Sql Server doesn't honor the ACL on this system view -- It's does to other system views (ex: sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Afaik referencing a linked server is not controlled by access control lists (ACLs). In other words, you cannot GRANT/DENY/REVOKE permission to *use* a linked server. You can certainly control the permission to *change* a linked server via `ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER` permission.

This apparent lack of permission is because the linked servers are forwarding specific credentials to the remote server, controlled via the impersonation or the remote_logins settings associated with the linked server. The actual access control happens on the remote server, using the credentials associated with the linked server. So in order to deny a group of users access to the linked server, you need to deny that group access to the remote server *on the remote server itself*.

Comment: Depending on your setup, I guess you could also attempt to use the login mapping feature.  Typically, I would prefer integrated security and handle everything with proper permissions on actual users based on their actual identity.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this. I remember using a tool on Sql Server 200 that would alter permissions on system objects to prevent some users from being able to see the list of linked servers, but not the ability to query them. In this case they can't use integrated security for all linked server, however for some I can modify the settings. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a workaround I just thought of:

On Linked Server Properties dialog box, Properties tab; add users that you *don't* want to access the linked server. Then, assign them some dummy user/pass combination that will be rejected on target server.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This works but would it be considered best practice?

Comment: Just an idea, but, you could flip this around to make it more secure. Assign a wrong password in the properties/security tab, and add entries for users that are allowed access, with the correct credentials. Just tested this. Seems to work. But this feels ... just plain wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

The type of authentication is of importance.  When you link the servers they have to be linked using Kerberos and then you can control the access on the linked server.  Otherwise your group will always be authenticated on the credentials specified in the link.

Answer (score 0):

AFACS, linked servers are missing proper access control.  I would like to do the following:

1. Create a credential for connecting to the remote server
2. Create a new linked server:
   a. Specify a server role or AD group or security as the local user
   b. Specify the credential as the remote user
3. Add logins to the server role or AD group to control access.

Answer (score 0):

Take your transact statement, put it into a SSIS package 'Execute SQL Task'

In the link server security properties, add the userid (on your server) you want to access the link server to the top section along with the uid and pw for the linked server and click the radio button 'not be made'

when you schedule your job in sql server agent, select your ssis package and use your proxy (db/security/credentials) on the run as line in the job step.

Answer (score 0):

DENY SELECT ON [sys].[sysservers] on <..>

Comment: correction: DENY SELECT ON [sys].[sysservers]  TO.. <user>

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [answer] to improve the perceived helpfulness of your post. You might also enjoy that you can indeed [edit] your post to improve it - instead of commenting what you would like to have written....